# Proving identity of this integral: $\dfrac{1}{\pi}\int_0^\pi \cos(n\theta-z\sin\theta)d\theta$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, bessel-functions

**Definitions:** We have an integral:
$$ A_n= \dfrac{1}{\pi}\int_0^\pi \cos(n\theta-z\sin\theta)d\theta, n=0,\pm 1,... $$
**Question:** How to prove this identity:
$$ A_{-n}=(-1)^n A_n$$
**My attempt:** I obtatin this easily:
$$A_{-n} = \dfrac{1}{\pi}\int_0^\pi \cos(n\theta+z\sin\theta)d\theta,$$
then I use substitution: $\theta = \pi - \varphi$:
$$A_{-n} = \dfrac{1}{\pi}\int_0^\pi \cos(n\pi -n\varphi + z\sin\varphi)(-1)d\varphi ,$$
By using formula for cosine of sum I obtain:
$$A_{-n} = \dfrac{1}{\pi}\int_0^\pi \cos(n\pi)\cos(n\varphi - z\sin\varphi)(-1)d\varphi,$$
$$A_{-n} =(-1)^{n+1} \dfrac{1}{\pi}\int_0^\pi  \cos(n\varphi - z\sin\varphi)d\varphi$$
Where did I make a mistake?

Comment: How did you obtain the easily obtained result?

Comment: @copper.hat $cos(-x)=cos(x)$

Comment: That would leave you with $-n\theta+z \sin \phi$.

Comment: @copper.hat By definition $A_{-n} = \dfrac{1}{\pi}\int_0^\pi \cos(-n\theta-z\sin\theta)d\theta.$ Now I use $\cos(-n\theta-z\sin\theta)=\cos(n\theta+z\sin\theta).$

Comment: Oops, excuse me, I missed the $-n$.

Comment: When you made the substitution you didn't change the limits of the integration.

Comment: No problem, Glad to be able to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As was commented, you forgot to change the bounds with your sub $\theta=\pi-\varphi$:
$$A_{-n}=\frac1\pi\int_\pi^0\cos(n\pi -n\varphi + z\sin\varphi)(-1)d\varphi
\\=-\frac1\pi\int^\pi_0\cos(n\pi -n\varphi + z\sin\varphi)(-1)d\varphi\\
=(-1)^nA_n$$